# SQL query for dynamic insert row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am having data like:

```
ItemCode          Attribute      PositionID   
ITEM-000032 CHESTSIZE   1
ITEM-000032 JACKETLEN            2
ITEM-000042 CHESTSIZE            1
ITEM-000042 JACKETLEN            2
**ITEM-000049   SLACKWAIST  1**
ITEM-000071 CHESTSIZE            1
ITEM-000071 JACKETLEN            2
ITEM-000074 CHESTSIZE            1
ITEM-000074 JACKETLEN            2
```

---

In above data except ITEM-000049 others are having perfect combination. so i want to create a new row for ITEM-000049
As

```
ITEM-000049 --  2
```

to make it perfect.

Kind regards,
Om

Comment: Why don't you just insert the new row?

Comment: You need to make it clearer what you want - "a perfect combination" makes no sense

Comment: After adding the row 




ITEM-000049 -- 2 





Output will like below: 




ItemCode Attribute PositionID 





ITEM-000032 CHESTSIZE 1 




ITEM-000032 JACKETLEN 2 




ITEM-000042 CHESTSIZE 1 





ITEM-000042 JACKETLEN 2 




ITEM-000049 SLACKWAIST 1 




ITEM-000049 -- 1 




ITEM-000071 CHESTSIZE 1




 ITEM-000071 JACKETLEN 2 




ITEM-000074 CHESTSIZE 1 




ITEM-000074 JACKETLEN 2

Comment: They are having positionID 1 & 2 except the ITEM-000049, so i want to add one row with PositionID = 2 & Attribute = -- for the same ItemCode.
Is that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like for each ItemCode, you are expecting 2 records, for 2 different Attributes.

So something like this is what I think you're after. Just run the SELECT part of it first without the INSERT to check it is indeed what you're after.

```
INSERT YourTable (ItemCode, Attribute, PositionID)
SELECT t.ItemCode, 'SECOND ATTRIBUTE', 2
FROM 
(
SELECT ItemCode
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ItemCode
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) t
```